# Creating Remote Shared Objects with Red5?

Tags: java, red5

I am in the process of teaching myself how to create applications using Red5.  I am having trouble making server side shared objects.

Right now I am trying to make a simple application that an objects is created by the server every time a user connects.  I want each client to be able to see the other objects that are connected.

Does anyone know where I find a good example of a Server Side Shared Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of our team members has created video tutorials for this very thing and more, you can find them on youtube at this url
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MuLnMKYe9k&playnext=1&list=PL310F0481BCE4D194&feature=results_main